# How do I make an addon run a function whenever a page is loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I am developing a Firefox addon and I want it to add an event listener on every form field. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// 'extension is loaded', you probably have this
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // run your_function() when page is loaded and DOM is ready
    gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", your_function, true);
}, false);
```

Comment: thanks. I tried the code in the javascript shell and it seems to work